# Highlight text of an incoming emails in Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

in my line of work i get dozens of emails with pretty much the same content.
i can't read them all, so i am looking for a solution that will enable me, upon opening an incoming mail, all the predefined words would be highlighted in a color.

I already tried to define new rules and on view settings-> conditioned formatting with no luck, it just highlights the subject and not the body.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do that. The only way to highlight text in message texts is the navigating through search results: you'll see results highlighted with yellow color.